# Waterloo Fermat contest 2020

Tags: contest-math

last Question: (not verbatim)
if x, y, z is between [0, 1], what is the probability that
$|x-y| >z$ and
$|x-z| >y$

In the contest, I had a very hard time trying to visualize and graph the graph of a cube which represents the x, y, z value and the inequalities itself. I'm trying to look for techniques or maybe references so I can easily graph 3d equations and inequalities.

I am also open to another solution besides 3d geometry that can be applied

Comment: First thought: If all the variable are between 0 and 1, are the absolute values necessary?

Comment: What do you mean by *"between $[0,1]$"*? What are the probability distributions of $x$, $y$ and $z$? Why do you take absolute values if all terms are positive anyway? Also note that the two inequalities together are equivalent to $x>|y-z|$.

Comment: sorry, supposed to be subtraction

Comment: The conditions translate to either ( x>y+z ) or ( y>x+z and z>x+y). Second condition isn't possible with given constraint [0,1]. So, the only condition that i see here is x-y-z>0. Now we need to find the volume of this region inside the unit cube

Comment: @Mathsmerizing in addition, $x-y-z\leq 1$. The region is formed by $4$ planes: $x-y-z=1$; $x=0$; $y=0$; and $z=0$. A pyramid with volume $\frac{1}{6}$

Answer (score 0):

From the inequalities, it is obvious that neither $y$ nor $z$ can be the biggest of the three. Thus $x$ is the biggest and the inequalities become $x>y+z$. Now we need to find the probability of $0\leq y< x$ and $0\leq z < x-y$ with probability density function of $x,y,z$ is a constant: $1$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(x>y+z)&=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{x}{\int_{0}^{x-y}{dz}\ dy}\ dx}\\
\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{x}{\left(x-y\right)\ dy}\ dx}\\
\\
&= \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{2}}{2} dx}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

Not sure if integral is permitted in this kind of competition though.

In $3D$ space, the region is a pyramid with its $4$ points: $(0,0,0);(1,0,0);(1,1,0);(1,0,1)$. This pyramid’s volume is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Building off your last line, the conditions in the question are given by 4 planes, and we want the volume contained within. Thus, we find the intersection point of each set of 3 planes, which defines the vertices of the pyramid like you have shown. (I suspect that's their approach the problem from an area perspective)